# jQuery UI: Re-initializing a function after loading content via AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

I've been searching all over for an answer to this question for a few days now, and while I have found most of the answer to my problem, there's still one piece of my code that is not working as it did before adding AJAX calls.

Some background:  I am creating a web app to serve as an RPG character generator.  One of the first things that happens is I create jQuery UI spinner widgets to adjust stat scores.  On the stop event, my code runs a function that checks the current number against a switch case to set a value to how many points are added or subtracted from an initial pool (Point-Buy system, for anyone who knows about these things):

```
function calcPtsLeft() {

        var ptssum = new Number();
        var ptsmax = new Number($("#maxpoints").val());

        var pbstr = pointBuy($strsc.val());
        var pbdex = pointBuy($dexsc.val());
        var pbcon = pointBuy($consc.val());
        var pbint = pointBuy($intsc.val());
        var pbwis = pointBuy($wissc.val());
        var pbcha = pointBuy($chasc.val());

        var ptssum = pbstr + pbdex + pbcon + pbint + pbwis + pbcha;

        ptsleft = ptsmax - ptssum;

        $("#ptsleft").val(ptsleft);
    };

    calcPtsLeft();
```

This code functioned properly, up until I decided to use AJAX calls to dynamically load various pages into a #content div.  After making the AJAX call to load my character generator, my widgets didn't show up at all.  I found that this was due to a delegation problem, so I collected all of my widget initialization into a function:

```
function initGenWidgets() {

//sets CSS for input/label items from jQuery UI set 
$("#slider input:text, #slider label, #remaining input:text, #remaining label, #charName, #charAge")
    .addClass("ui-spinner ui-spinner-input");   

//initialize jQuery UI button widget
$("button").button();

//initialize jQuery UI radio buttonset widget
$("#genderbuttons").buttonset();

//initialize jQuery UI menu widget
$("#raceradio").menu();

//initialize jQuery UI vertical tabs
$("#char-gen").tabs().addClass("ui-tabs-vertical ui-helper-clearfix");

$("#char-gen li").removeClass("ui-corner-top").addClass("ui-corner-left");

//initialize jQuery UI spinner widget for age
$("#charAge").spinner({
    icons: {
        down: "ui-icon-minus",
        up: "ui-icon-plus"
    }
});

//initialize jQuery UI spinner widget for stats
$(".statspinner").spinner({
        min : 7,
        max : 18,
        icons : {
            down : "ui-icon-minus",
            up : "ui-icon-plus"
        },
        stop: function(event, ui) {
            calcPtsLeft();
        }
    });

//initialize jQuery UI slider widget for point-buy allotment
$("#pointslider").slider({
        value: 20,
        min: 15,
        max: 40,
        step: 5,
        slide: function(event, ui) {
            $("#maxpoints").val(ui.value);
            calcPtsLeft();
        }
    });
};
```

I now make the AJAX call as follows:

```
//function to load php files into content div
function loadContent($page){
    $("#content").load($page+' > *', function(response, status){
            success: initGenWidgets();
    });
};

//nav links load files into content div
$(".menulink").on("click", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    loadContent($(this).attr("href"));
});
```

Everything seems to load fine, but when I test the widgets, it seems that my spinners no longer execute the `calcPtsLeft()` function on stop.  The slider works to update the #ptsLeft value after I slide it (going to fix that later), but the spinners do not update the value at all.

What am I doing wrong here, or not doing at all here?  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: that should not be executing fine... it has a serious syntax error. `success: initGenWidgets();` -> `initGenWidgets();`

Comment: I took the "success:" part out of the loadContent() function.  The widgets still initialize fine, as they did prior, but the calcPtsLeft() function still doesn't seem to work.

Comment: why doesn't it work? does it not get executed? is some part of it not containing the right value? do some debugging.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### jQuery [`.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/):

**Script Execution**

> When calling `.load()` using a URL without a suffixed selector
>   expression, the content is passed to .`html()` prior to scripts being
>   removed. This executes the script blocks before they are discarded. If
>   `.load()` is called with a selector expression appended to the URL,
>   however, the scripts are stripped out prior to the DOM being updated,
>   and thus are not executed. An example of both cases can be seen below

A small but important segment of the docs for `.load()`! If you really wanted to execute them, you'll probably have to do some sort of `eval()`, or discard the `.selector`

### Example:

Here, any JavaScript loaded into `#a` as a part of the document will successfully execute.

```
$( "#a" ).load( "article.html" );
```

However, in the following case, script blocks in the document being loaded into `#b` are stripped out and **not** executed:

```
$( "#b" ).load( "article.html #target" );
```

### Possible Solution

Well, after testing - I decided to actually take the step of adding the functions to the window, simply because it's the best way of carrying across functions & methods via many scripts. This, hopefully fixes have undefined functions being declared, because you're in a different script & namespace.

**Main.php**

```
<script>

    //Create Rgp Object
    var Rgp = {
       calcPtsLeft : function() {
            console.log( 'Calculate Points' );
       },
       addPoints : function() {
            //Some addPoints Function
       }
    }; 

    //Add Object to Window      
    window.Rgp = Rgp;

    $('#begin').on('click', function() {
        $("#content").load( 'someScript.js', function( response, status ){
            success: initGenWidgets();
        });
    });

</script>
```

**someScript.js**

```
<script>
function initGenWidgets() {
   $("#pointslider").slider({
       value: 20,
       min: 15,
       max: 40,
       step: 5,
       slide: function(event, ui) {
            $("#maxpoints").val(ui.value);
            Rgp.calcPtsLeft(); //Prints 'Calculate Points'
       }
   });
}
</script>
```

Comment: Attempted this possible fix - didn't work.  For some reason, it seems as if the `calcPtsLeft()` function just isn't doing what it's supposed to do.  I'm debugging now, but it just seems really weird that it works perfectly well if I load the page on its own, but breaks after AJAX.

Thanks for the suggestion though.  These little tidbits are helping me to understand how jQuery works more and more.

Comment: I'll edit in some debugging ideas in a sec =), We'll get to the bottom of it! :D

Comment: Also, `initGenWidgets();` and `calcPtsLeft();` are in the same .load()'ed file?

Comment: I've done some testing, I believe your `calcPtsLeft()` is in the main .js file, but the `initGenWidgets()` from `.load()` is being called in..

Comment: Yeah, everything is in one js file.  `initGenWidgets()` was created recently, to solve the problem of widget initialization needing to be delegated.  Though, `calcPtsLeft()` should still be able to be called regardless, if the js file is being loaded in to the main page...right?

Comment: Well, it basically means your calPtsLeft() is a different script entirely, thus - doesn't exist when you call it from initGenWidgets(). I'm just typing up a solution for you, which eliminates the fact that some functions are declared in different scripts.

Comment: There you go, Updated. As you're re-calling functions from various scripts - you're better off making an object that keeps it within one namespace, namely the window - That way, you can call `Rpg.function()` wherever you are, when after loading etc.

Comment: I had some issues actually creating an object to contain the functions that perform the needed calculations, and I tried to do this in the main PHP page...but then, thinking about what you said about keeping things in the one namespace, I actually moved both the `calcPtsLeft()` and `pointBuy()` (my function to assign a point value to each number) into the PHP page that contains the code for the generator itself...and it worked!  Thank you so much!  If I could upvote your answer, I'd not only do it once, but as many times as I could without my clicking finger falling off!

Comment: Awesome :D!! Glad you were able to move forward, sucks to be stuck on something like that for a while, good luck with the rest of the project dude :-)